# RewriteRule [L] still changing the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I found myself with this problem, which is driving me a little bit crazy. I use apache's mod_rewrite for pretty URLs and I need to use dynamic subdomains in the site. Everything is great and all the server has de wildcards. I use the next code on my .htacess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/%1 [L]
```

The only problem is, even if I use the [L] flag the url of the site change to `http://mysite.com/subdomain`. What i want is the url to be like `http://subdomain.mysite.com`

The link `mysite.com/subdomain` is a dynamic url and is solved with another rule with the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ filter.php?type=subdomain&subdomain=$1
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you specify an external URL (which changing the subdomain does), a header redirect will take place. I don't think you can prevent that. But why not skip that step altogether, and use the second RewriteRule straight away?

I can't test this right now, but something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).mysite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ filter.php?type=subdomain&subdomain=$1
```

should work.

Comment: thank you, that's what i end up doing, and then i make a condition so if the page accessed this way i change the <base href="" /> to fix the links and css